# How to Go About Click Event Under Focus Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is to have a `hidden` div displayed whenever my input box gains `focus` and to be able select a value and populate the textbox with. 
Then make the displayed div `fadeOut`.

```
<div class='_date'>
    <div class='birth_date'>
        <p class='year'>1970</p>
        <p class='year'>1971</p>
        <p class='year'>1972</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='text' name='date_year' id = 'birth_year'>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.birth_date').hide();
$('body').on('focus', '#birth_year' ,function (e) {
    $('.birth_date').show();
     //this is where my click event comes in...
})
```

How to achieve this `bubbles` in my head and I am a bit confused on how to try it out.

See the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.birth_date').hide();
$(document).on('focus', '#birth_year' ,function (e) {
    $('.birth_date').show();
});
```

on click retrieve the value of the element.
and insert it has the value of your input. (then fadeOut)

`click()` toggle off the `is.(":focus")` , the `mousedown()` does not. So you can check if the user is still focusing the good input when he click a `.year`.

```
$('.year').mousedown(function(){
    if ($('#birth_year').is(":focus")) {
        var year = $(this).html();
        $('#birth_year').val(year);
        $('.birth_date').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Edit: ok, you can also test the focus. Like that you populate and hide the input just if the focus is on it.

Comment: This works but I want the click event to come under `mousedwon` event because I have other things to it.

Comment: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donkino/qu6vovf4/)
I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe

```
<div id="content">
<div class='_date'>
    <div class='birth_date'>
        <p class='year'>1970</p>
        <p class='year'>1971</p>
        <p class='year'>1972</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <input type='text' name='date_year' id = 'birth_year' />
</div>

$('#birth_year').mousedown(function (e) {
    $('._date').show();
});


$('.year').click(function(){
    $('#birth_year').val($(this).text());
    $('._date').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/wgLgcdt2/

Comment: This works but I want the click event to come under `mousedwon` event because I have other things to it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more descriptive of what you want to do with mousedown? Your question asks how to display box when input receives focus and how to receive a click from inside the div (or maybe I'm misunderstanding something). This will show the year div when the input receives a focus:

```
$(function () {
    $(".birth_date").hide();
    $("#birth_year").on("focus", function (e) {
        $(".birth_date").show();
        this.blur();
    });
    $(".year").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#birth_year").val($(this).html());
        $(".birth_date").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='_date'>
    <div class='birth_date'>
        <p class='year'>1970</p>
        <p class='year'>1971</p>
        <p class='year'>1972</p>
        <p class='year'>1973</p>
        <p class='year'>1974</p>
        <p class='year'>1975</p>
        <p class='year'>1976</p>
        <p class='year'>1977</p>
        <p class='year'>1978</p>
    </div>
    <input readonly type='text' name='date_year' id = 'birth_year' />
</div>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh9s6x6o/1/

Comment: Can I put the `$('.year').on('click'....` under ` $("#birth_year").on("focus"...`? That's what I want to achieve and it is stated there in jQuery code as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var highlightedyear = $('.year').val();
$('#birthyear').html(highlightedyear);
```

that gives you the initially selected value, then as it changes....

```
$('.year').on('change', function(){
var highlightedyear = $('.year').val();
$('#birthyear').html(highlightedyear);
});
```

but I would give the multi input selector an ID instead of selecting by class